# Is there existing plugins to "Click-to-Launch" embedded Flash / SWF content?

Tags: plugins, content, embed, activation, flash

I'm aware that there is existing FlashBlock plugins that users can install on their browsers, but I would like a Wordpress approach to be able to:

- Replace SWF content by a thumbnail / screenshot of the Flash content (could be manually prepared).
- When clicked on, activates it OR launches a "popin" DIV container to play the Flash file inside of it.
- When other SWF content exists on the same page, automatically close other SWFs (only one can play at a time).

If you know of anything that works similarly, I'd be interested to know about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

Embed this script: http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/jquery.flash.js

Then in your functions.js

```
    (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $(".flash").click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent().empty().flash({ 
                src: $(this).attr('href')
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    })(jQuery);
```

Your markup would be something like:

```
<div class="flash-container">
    <a href="flash.swf"><img src="placeholder.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

For more info check http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/

i hope this makes some sense :-) Btw: this isn't a WordPress question, so maybe you get a faster and or better answer @ stackoverflow.com